# Can I use a VPN to trick minecraft into connecting via LAN?

Tags: vpn, lan, minecraft

I recently purchased Minecraft for a younger cousin of mine. Her best friend and Minecraft playmate is another cousin. However, they live in two separate houses.

In the interest of setting up a server in the easiest way possible (without running the server software on any computer, ie in such a way that I could install a few programs and then leave day-to-day operation to an 11-year-old), is it possible to use a VPN to connect two computers such that they would believe that they were on the same network, allowing use of Minecraft's "Open to LAN" feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have a bridged network VPN.  OpenVPN, for example, can do this, [in TAP mode](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html).